# How to display customer's payment methods on client side using Braintree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, braintree

I'm aware of using the customerId to retrieve the information stored in Braintree for the customer. I'm curious if there is an easy way to display this on the UI using the v3 drop-in for nodejs. I attached a screenshot of what i'm wanting to achieve. The UI in the drop-in that I am interested in is titled "Paying with Card". This is straight from the Braintree documentation.

Thanks[image: Stored Payment methods]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after digging through the documentation[image]